# OpenGTS: error trying to use the standard map provider

Tags: openlayers

I've changed my standard map provider to Google Maps V3 successfully by editing the private.xml in %GTS_HOME% directory and the private.xml in the %CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/track/WEB-INF/ directory. Now I'd like to get back the standard map provider OpenLayers. I thought setting the Google Maps active=true to active=false and setting the openLayers active=false to active=true would work. But if I try to log in to the frontend and click on 'vehicle map' an error occurs with the following message:

> [jsMapInit]: openLayers
>
> Error initializing map
>
> (map provider service may be temporarily unavailable)
>
> ReferenceError: "OpenLayers" is not defined

Could someone please help me? I really stuck at this point.. :(

Comment: What is GTS_HOME? OpenLayers is not defined usually means that the OpenLayers.js file has not downloaded properly, or has not finished downloading when you first try and call it.

Comment: GTS_HOME is the home directory of the opengts project. But it worked before I changed the map provider to Google Maps so do you know what else it can be? I also tried to use my backup but it didn't worked too..

Comment: There are a myriad of things that can go wrong with a server configuration. Can you provide the HTML/Javascript that your server is producing, as a first step?

Comment: I've solved the problem by updating the OpenGTS project to version 2.5.5 so now it is working! :)
But I have a new problem.. my task for now is that the server has to send a phone book from the database to a device after the device has connected to the server. My problem is that I don't know where I can find the java class (or the file in general) which is handling the incoming connections.. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Could someone help me please?